# Should a block literal retain referenced heap-allocated blocks

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Consider the following code:

```
// t included so block1 is a stack block. See [1] below
int t = 1;
SimpleBlock block1 = ^{ NSLog(@"block1, %d", t); };

// copy block1 to the heap
SimpleBlock block1_copied = [block1 copy];

// block2 is allocated on the stack, and refers to
// block1 on the stack and block1_copied on the heap
SimpleBlock block2 = ^{
    NSLog(@"block2");
    block1_copied();
    block1();
};
[block1_copied release];

// When the next line of code is executed, block2_copied is
// allocated at the same memory address on on the heap as
// block1_copied, indicating that block1_copied has been
// deallocated. Why didn't block2 retain block1_copied?

SimpleBlock block2_copied = [block2 copy];
block2_copied();
[block2_copied release];
```

Where, for completeness, SimpleBlock is defined by:

```
typedef void (^SimpleBlock)(void);
```

As indicated by the comment in the code, my tests (using both GCC 4.2 and LLVM 2.0) show that block1_copied is deallocated by the time [block2 copy] is called, yet according to the documentation that I have read [1,3], blocks are objective-c objects and blocks retain objective-c objects to which they refer [2] (in the non-instance variable case).

Additionally, note that when block2 is copied, its reference to block1 is also changed to a reference to a new copy of block1 (which is different than block1_copied), as expected, since blocks copy any blocks to which they refer [2].

So, what's going on here?

A) If blocks retain objective-c objects to which they refer and blocks are objective-c objects, why is block1_copied deallocated before block2 goes out of scope?

B) If blocks copy blocks to which they refer, and if sending -(id)copy to a heap-allocated block actually just increments its retain count, why is block1_copied deallocated before block2 goes out of scope?

C) If this is the expected behavior, where is the documentation that explains it?

[1] http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/how-blocks-are-implemented-and.html
[2] http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html
[3] http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.txt

Footnote: In my tests, the result of running this code is an infinitely recursive call to block2_copied(), since block1_copied() had the same memory address as block2_copied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This is the specification](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.txt).  It is slightly stale right now and doesn't have the formalism of a normal spec.  However, Blocks have been proposed in the C working group and a more formal specification has been discussed in that context.

Specifically, the spec says:

> The Block_copy operator retains all
>   objects held in variables of automatic
>   storage referenced within the Block
>   expression (or form strong references
>   if running under garbage collection). 
>   Object variables of __block storage
>   type are assumed to hold normal
>   pointers with no provision for retain
>   and release messages.

Thus, the behavior you are seeing is correct, though it is definitely a pitfall!

A block won't retain anything until the block is copied.  Like blocks starting on the stack, this is largely a performance based decision.

If you were to change your code to:

```
SimpleBlock block2_copied = [block2 copy];
[block1_copied release];
```

It behaves as expected.

The static analyzer should catch that, but does not (Please [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com/)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just filed a bug on the static analyzer. I think this is also a developer documentation inaccuracy, given the text from "Blocks Programming Topics" > "Blocks and Variables" > "Object and Block Variables" > "Objective-C Objects". None of the text here indicates that the retain only happens _after_ the block is copied. I'll file a second bug on developer documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I note the same seems to happen with normal objects. This code:

```
NSNumber *foo = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:42];
void(^block)(void) = ^{ NSLog(@"foo = %@", foo); };
[foo release];
NSNumber *foo2 = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:43];
void(^block_copy)(void) = [block copy];
block_copy();
```

Prints "foo = 43"

It *might* be expected behavior. To quote Apple's documentation:

> When you copy a block, any references to other blocks from within that block are copied if necessary

At the point `block1_copy` is released, `block2` hasn't been copied yet.

Comment: That's definitely true. So this might be the expected behavior. Reference [2] also says "In a reference-counted environment, by default when you reference an Objective-C object within a block, it is retained. This is true even if you simply reference an instance variable of the object. Object variables marked with the `__block` storage type modifier, however, are not retained." This says nothing about copying being necessary, though it might be given these examples. Later on they do mention that referenced _blocks_ are copied if necessary. These seem like they might be different issues though.

Comment: @AndrewHershberger: True. The big problem is that there isn't a real specification.

Comment: @anomie, You don't refer to foo2 anywhere in this snippet, yet you claim that output is the value of foo2. How is this even possible?

Comment: @Comptrol: foo is released and freed, because blocks don't retain referenced objects until they're copied. Then foo2 happens to be allocated at the same memory location. Or at least that was true in 2011, I haven't checked if they've fixed it since.